# want to print the value of the variable in URL in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
function Entry(content){
  var Country=content;
  ...
  $(".helplink").attr("href","123/456/789//html/help.htm?href=" XXXXX ".htm")
}
```

In above code I want to print the value of the variable Country in place of XXXXX..

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just concatenate the strings?

```
function Entry(content){ 
    var Country=content;
    $(".helplink").attr("href","123/456/789//html/help.htm?href=" + Country + ".htm") 
}
```

I'm not quite sure if I've understood you correctly or not, but I don't have enough reputation to comment. If this isn't what you're after, please can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

use slice to get first and last part of attribute and concatenate you required value in it.

```
var v =  $(".helplink").attr("href");
var index = 'href="';
var character = "country";
v = v.slice(0,v.indexOf(index)+index.length)+character+ v.slice(v.indexOf(index)+index.length + character.length,v.length );
$(".helplink").attr("href", v);
```